# Is it worth to put instance of class inside interface?

Tags: java, oop

I'm trying to learn some basics about OOP in `Java`.

I read about interface. My question is: is it worth to use instances of class inside interface? I'm not sure, but I think it could reduce amount of instances among code, e.g:

```
public interface mergingInterface
{
    ArrayClass ac = new ArrayClass();
    LinkedListClass llc = new LinkedListClass();
}
```

then I just can do:

```
public class LinkedListClass implements mergingInterface
{
    LinkedList link = new LinkedList();
    public void filling()
    {
        ac.someMethodFromArrayClass();
        //some method
    }
}
```

and many classes may use one object. Is it worth? Is my thinking correct?

Comment: If you're talking about having fields inside the interface: you can't do that. Interfaces do not contain state, only method signatures. You can have similar setup using abstract class, but unless the field is static, each class instance has its own object value.

Comment: Also, you should learn naming conventions. For example, class names in java must start with Upper-Case letter and use `PascalCase`.

Answer (score 2):

No! The point of an interface is that it's decoupled from its implementations. Any class should be able to implement it *without* having to modify it. In your example, you would have to modify `mergingInterface` to have an instance of every implementer.